Accessing docker Node-Red from server
I`ve created a Node-red container on my server using docker with the below parameters:



CONTAINER ID
IMAGE
COMMAND
CREATED
STATUS
PORTS
NAMES




79c1e04f442e
noderedv2
"./entrypoint.sh"
52 minutes ago
Up 26 minutes (healthy)
0.0.0.0:5322->1880/tcp
nodered



The Ui is accessible if I use the serverhostname:5322 and works perfectly. What i don`t undestand is when tryng to use the nginx reverse proxy configuration installed on the server (not as a container):
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  page.com;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;


        location /tools {
                proxy_pass http://serverhostname:5322;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }

From my basic understanding it should show me the Node-red UI but only get the message
"Cannot GET /tools" when trying to access http://page.com/tools
Any advice on how to get this to work through http://page.com/tools, is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

What do they nginx logs show? Also what happens if you add a slash to the end of the location

@hardillb Unfortunately i don't have access to the nginx logs to see, will try to see if i can get them from the team that has access to them.  Adding the slash had no effect.
